# How can I improve this method. Is there any php native method available to match the range?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to refactor this method

```
public function getRange($currentWeight, $maxWeight)
{
    $shades = array(
        '0-10' => 'Range0-10',
        '10-20' => 'Range10-20',
        '20-30' => 'Range20-30',
        '30-40' => 'Range30-40',
        '40-50' => 'Range40-50',
        '50-60' => 'Range50-60',
        '60-70' => 'Range60-70',
        '70-80' => 'Range70-80',
        '80-90' => 'Range80-90',
        '90-100' => 'Range90-100'
    );

$weightPercent = ($currentWeight * 100) / $maxWeight;

foreach ($shades as $colorRange => $colorClass) {
    $range = explode('-', $colorRange);

    if ($weightPercent >= $range[0] && $weightPercent <= $range[1]) {
        $selectedColor = $colorClass;
    }
}

    return $selectedColor;
}
```

Is there any native php function available which can give me the range of a number or is there any other way of doing this better?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering, if you have a `$wieghtPercent` of 10, it could be in range 0-10 and in 10-20. It will pick range 0-10 tough, because thats the first match. But it doesn't seem really right.

Comment: You certainly should not use strings and string operations for mathematical computations. Use integer threshold values instead and a modulo division.

Answer (score 1):

my version:

```
public function getRange($currentWeight, $maxWeight)
{   
    $weight = intval(($currentWeight * 100) / $maxWeight / 10) * 10;
    return 'Range' . $weight .'-' . ($weight +10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something to keep your values in range:

```
public function getRange($currentWeight, $maxWeight){

    $range_base = intval(($currentWeight * 100) / $maxWeight / 10) * 10;

    if($range_base >= 0 && $range_base <= 100 && $currentWeight<=$maxWeight){ 

        if($range_base == 100) { $range_base = $range_base - 10; }
        return 'Range' . $range_base .'-' . ($range_base +10); 

    }else{ 
        return false; // Out of range
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version using `range`, `bcsub`, `array_search` and `array_slice` functions:

```
function getRange($currentWeight, $maxWeight)
{
    if ($currentWeight > $maxWeight) {  // considering max threshold
        throw new Exception("weight is out of range!");
    }
    $colorRange = range(0, 100, 10);
    $weightPercent = ($currentWeight * 100) / $maxWeight;
    $lower_boundary_key = array_search(intval(bcsub(floor($weightPercent), $weightPercent % 10, 0)), $colorRange);
    $range = array_slice($colorRange, $lower_boundary_key, 2);

    return 'Range' . implode("-", $range);
}

print_r(getRange(41.5, 200));   // outputs: "Range20-30"

print_r(getRange(201.5, 200));  // will throw "Exception: weight is out of range! ..."
```